# Get Random Number Between Given Range in Java

Tags: java, random, range

How to Get Random Number Between Given Range in Java if minimum is more than 1? for example if i want to get random number between 6 to 20. currently i am using this code

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int  rnd = rand.nextInt(499) + 1;
```

it is working well, but if i change 1 to some high number for example 6, it will not work properly, i want to get random number that is between 6 and 20. is it possible using above function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply calculate a random number between 0 and 14, than add 6

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int  rnd = rand.nextInt(14) + 6;
```

Comment: Nice Trick. it means Java do not have proper function to get random between given range, and we have to use some trick to get this...?

Comment: Exactly, basically any range can be seen as a range from 0 to to size of range plus the distance from 0 of minimum value